# How to use Anchor tag in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

Ia m trying to get link for a text as output from my xslt but I am not getting the text as hyperlink: below is the code I am using:

```
<xsl:choose>
 <xsl:when test="XXXXXX='XXX'">
        <p>If we may be of further assistance, please </p>
        <html><body><a href="http://example.com/">contact us</a></body></html>

        Sincerely,              
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
        test
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Do you mean you are using `<xsl:output method="text" />` in your XSLT?

Comment: Basically I am getting out put this program as email, In that email I am expecting below :  If we may be of further assistance, please contactus, here contact us should be a hyperLink when I click on that it should redirect me to example.com

Comment: If you want to output a hyperlink, you will need to have <xsl:output method="html" /> in your XSLT, and also ensure your email message is set to have an html body.

Comment: where do I need to use this <xsl:output method="html" />? under template tag?

Comment: It needs to go under the <xsl:stylesheet> tag.